# Is there a way to make a string with sequential numbers without using a for-loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I would ike to make a string with digits like this: `123456789`.
I can write this easily with a `for` loop.

```
x = ""
for i in range(1, 10):
    x += str(i)
```

However, I would like to write this with no explicit `for` loops.
Are there any creative ways, to do this?

Comment: Any solution that is not `x = '123456789'` will be some kind of a loop, even if not an explicit one that you can see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for the sake of it, you could use a recursive function if you really wanted:

```py
def stringer(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return '1'

    return stringer(n-1) + str(n)
```

What the function does is return the string `123...n` by calling itself recursively, decreasing `n` each time until reaching `1`, and then building the string on the way back.

If called as `print(stringer(9))` this will give:

```
123456789
```

No loops there, just a nice call stack

Answer (score 3):

You could create the range as follows:

```
rangeToConvert = range(1, 10)
```

And than join the list to create a string. Only issue is that the values in the rangeToConvert are ints so you need to convert them to string in order to use the join function.

```
x = ''.join(map(str, rangeToConvert))
```

X would be in this case:

```
'123456789'
```

Answer (score 1):

Should you wish to use the `itertools` module of python you could do something like this:

```
from itertools import takewhile, count
x = ''
x = ''.join(map(str, takewhile(lambda x: x < 10, count(1))))
print(x)
```

When the above code snippet runs, it prints:

```
123456789
```